# Jhipster/Angular 7 - How to subscribe to retry request made by an interceptor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, jhipster

I'm working on a project with JHipster 5.8.2 and I want to add the capability of doing login again without doing any redirect. That way users don't lose their data. The problem is that my components are subscribed to the original request (the one that fails because the token is not valid anymore) and I'd like to subscribe to the retry request. Is there any way I can do this? Below are snippets of significant code

AuthExpiredInterceptor.ts

```js
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((error, caught) => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                    this.refreshToken(error).pipe(switchMap(
                        () => {
                            const token = this.localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken') 
                                   || this.sessionStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
                            if (!!token) {
                                request = request.clone({
                                    setHeaders: {
                                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            // The request I want to subscribe
                            return next.handle(request);
                        })).subscribe();
                }
                return caught;
            }
            )
        );
    }
```

Subscription to the result

```js
protected subscribeToSaveResponse() {
        let result=this.http.post<IObject>(this.resourceUrl, object, { observe: 'response' });
        result.subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IObject>) => this.onSaveSuccess(),
                        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onSaveError());
}
```

Thanks in advance